# How to run watch app on background mode location update

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I was using location updates as background mode on Apple Watch series 2..
my issue is when I removed app from dock or foreground. my app is again re-launching to foreground after unlocking watch.
But I don't want to re-launch app automatically until user manually re-launchig the app. How I can achieve this...
is their any way to handle this...